# Visual studio 2015 extension finding tfs url

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, visual-studio-extensions

I am trying to get a VS 2015 extension to connect the tfs currently in use.  I found a solution

```
TeamFoundationServerExt tfExt = DTE.GetObject("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.TeamFoundationServerExt") as TeamFoundationServerExt;
return tfExt.ActiveProjectContext.DomainUri;
```

unfortunately I think `TeamFoundationServerExt` is not meant to be used in Visual Studio 2015`can someone confirm this and tell me how it should be done

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I create a demo and test the code by using visual studio 2015, the variable named tfExt return null, If the solution is opened in the VS IDE, Team Explorer will automatically connect to the TFS server which binds to the solution. So we can use the DTE object to get the SourceControlExt object, then retrieve the TFS server information from its properties.

```
VersionControlExt vce;
VersionControlExplorerExt vcee;

DTE2 dte = this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(SDTE)) as DTE2;
dte.ExecuteCommand("View.TfsSourceControlExplorer");
vce = dte.GetObject("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.VersionControlExt") as VersionControlExt;
vcee = vce.Explorer;
var tfsServerName = vcee.Workspace.VersionControlServer.TeamFoundationServer.Uri;
```

please add the following reference.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. The latest documentation on the VersionControlExt class (like the TeamFoundationServerExt class I am using) is for Visual studio 2013.   It looks like there is no replacement for Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.dll

Comment: Yes, the dll(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.dll) Could also be found in vs 2016 installation folder, such as C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\hdalyazr.nyu

Comment: the last part of the path is different (I suspect its machine dependant) for me but it got me to the right area.  I had found a NuGet package Microsoft.TeamFoundation.ObjectModel that had the dll in it. it does have the "problem" that is dependent on .net 4.5..  This meant I had to use early versions of some other packages I needed.

Comment: why not use the dll in visual studio 2015.